# React Hooks: Can't perform a React state update on a component that hasn't mounted yet

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

**Edit 1**

I have updated my code (changed from useState to useEffect) but seems like the same problem. Only if I remove the `return` code, it runs perfectly. Seems like it happens when I have lots of data to show in view

**Edit 2**

I updated my useEffect() to below but still the same problem.

```js
 useEffect(() => {
        let mounted = true;
        if (mounted) {
            FetchOrderDetails();
        }
        return () => (mounted = false);
        
    }, []);
```

**Edit Ends**

I get this warning sometimes and it crashes `Warning: Can't perform a React state update on a component that hasn't mounted yet. This indicates that you have a side-effect in your render function that asynchronously later calls tries to update the component. Move this work to useEffect instead.`

Surprisingly, sometimes the code runs perfectly which most of the time it doesn't. What is wrong?

My code

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import { useCookies } from "react-cookie";

import * as Constants from "../Constants";
import HeaderTemplate from "../Templates/HeaderTemplate";

const OrderDetails = () => {
    const { transactionRefNo, transactionId } = useParams();
    const [cookies] = useCookies(["user"]);
    const [orderDetails, setOrderDetails] = useState([]);

    const FetchOrderDetails = async () => {
        let options = {
            employeeid: parseInt(cookies.employeeId),
            transactionid: parseInt(transactionId),
        };


        await fetch(Constants.API_ENDPOINT + "/test/orderdetails", {
            method: "POST",
            body: JSON.stringify(options),
        })
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((data) => setOrderDetails(data.order));
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(transactionRefNo, transactionId);
        FetchOrderDetails();
    }, []);

    return (
        <div>
            <HeaderTemplate />
            <React.Fragment>
                {/* Order Details Starts*/}
                <div className="panel panel-default mt-4">
                    <div className="panel-heading">
                        <h6 className="panel-title">Order Details</h6>
                    </div>
                    <div className="panel-body">
                        <b>
                            <small>
                                {"Order #" +
                                    orderDetails["transaction_reference_no"]}
                            </small>
                        </b>
                        <div className="row">
                            <div className="col-md-6">
                                <small>Port: {orderDetails["port"]}</small>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div className="row">
                            <div className="col-md-6">
                                <small>
                                    Type:{" "}
                                    {orderDetails["transaction_type"] ===
                                    "selling_stages"
                                        ? "Selling"
                                        : "Buying"}
                                </small>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                {/* Order Details Ends*/}

               


                
            </React.Fragment>
        </div>
    );
};
export default OrderDetails;
```

Comment: You wanted to use `useEffect` not `useState`

Comment: Still the same error?

Comment: Did you try to clean up the async function in useEffect (unsubscribing)?

Comment: Maybe you implemented the cleanup wrongly.

Comment: I found this for you I hope it helps: https://dev.to/elijahtrillionz/cleaning-up-async-functions-in-reacts-useeffect-hook-unsubscribing-3dkk

Comment: @DINO, it seems the same problem happens. I have updated my question with an edit

Comment: `useEffect` won't run on a component that's not mounted. The problem is that you sometimes end up calling `setOrderDetails(data.order)` after the component has unmounted.

Comment: @super, but I added **Edit 2** in my question to avoid that. Any idea why that's still happening?

Comment: A more idiomatic approach is to use a state-management library to store the data you fetch, then pass said data down to the component that displays it. If your needs are not to complicated  libraries like react-query or swr uses a built in cache layer witch will solve that for you for example.

Comment: You **Edit 2** only stops `FetchOrderDetails`. What happens if that function is called and then the component is unmounted before your fetch is done?

Comment: As I said, `useEffect` will never run on an unmounted component, so making the check there is pointless. The check needs to happen before calling `setOrderDetails(data.order)` since the whole chain of events is async.

Comment: Got your point @super. Will try to use some state management library

Comment: Another option that doesn't involve libraries is to use an [AbortController](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AbortController).

Comment: The article I posted has a section where he talks about AbortController and how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out, useEffect tries to update the state both when it mounts and unmounts. Hence the error occurs. As suggested by @super, I used swr to circumvent the issue in my case

```js
import React from "react";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import { useCookies } from "react-cookie";

import * as Constants from "../Constants";
import HeaderTemplate from "../Templates/HeaderTemplate";

const fetcher = async (cookies, transactionId) => {
    let options = {
        employeeid: parseInt(cookies.employeeId),
        transactionid: parseInt(transactionId),
    };

    const res = await fetch(Constants.API_ENDPOINT + "/test/orderdetails", {
        method: "POST",
        body: JSON.stringify(options),
    });
    const json = await res.json();
    return json;
};

const OrderDetails = () => {
   
    const { transactionRefNo, transactionId } = useParams();
    const [cookies] = useCookies(["user"]);
    const { data, error } = useSwr([cookies, transactionId], fetcher);

    if (!data) return <div>Loading...</div>;
    if (error) return <div>Error</div>;

    return (
        <div>
            <HeaderTemplate />
            <React.Fragment>
                {/* Order Details Starts*/}
                <div className="panel panel-default mt-4">
                    <div className="panel-heading">
                        <h6 className="panel-title">Order Details</h6>
                    </div>
                    <div className="panel-body">
                        <b>
                            <small>
                                {"Order #" +
                                    data.order.transaction_reference_no}
                            </small>
                        </b>
                        <div className="row">
                            <div className="col-md-6">
                                <small>Port: {data.order.port}</small>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div className="row">
                            <div className="col-md-6">
                                <small>
                                    Type:{" "}
                                    {data.order.transaction_type ===
                                    "selling_stages"
                                        ? "Selling"
                                        : "Buying"}
                                </small>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                {/* Order Details Ends*/}
            </React.Fragment>
        </div>
    );
};
export default OrderDetails;
```